# Dont know how to make or and and statements within an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I make an `if` statement have two values that are synonyms ie "display" and "screen" and then an `and` and another string such as "broken".  The idea is is that it would only output if there was a "display" and "broken" or "screen" and "broken".

What I have tried:

```
def issuesection():
    issue = input("Type in your issue in a sentence and we will try out best to help you with a solution:  ")
    if "display" or "screen" in issue and "broken" in issue:
        print('WORKED')
    else:
        print("FAIL")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Python sees:

```
"display" or "screen" in issue
```

as:

```
("display") or ("screen" in issue)
```

So it evaluates the *truthness* of `"display"` and **every non-empty string is considered to be `True`**.

So you should rewrite it to:

```
if "display" in issue or "screen" in issue and "broken" in issue:
```

Furthermore since you want the `and` to bind to both `in` checks, you should also brackets as the left operand of the `and`:

```
if ("display" in issue or "screen" in issue) and "broken" in issue:
```

Now it thus says: "*The condition holds if display or screen is in issue; **and** broken is in issue as well*". Without the brackets it would state:
 "*The condition holds if display is in issue; **or** screen and broken are in issue*".

Comment: Is this the most compact way?

Comment: probably yes, although code minimization is a very hard problem.

Comment: you can also do `any(x in issue for x in ["display","screen"])`, well for this example is longer, but you can build the list in other place and/or add more stuff to it so is more scalable

Comment: @Copperfield: yeah I demonstrated that in a previous answer, but as you say yourself, it is longer.